# What do these Asian Characters and Stamp Means?

Tags: characters

Can anyone tell me what this stamp and Asian content means? Who is the author? Thank you in advance.[image]

---

Thanks so much! I appreciate your help.

Comment: Thanks so much! I appreciate your help.

Comment: Tang Ho, I’d like to pay you to translate Asian Stamps and Signatures. Can you help? If yes, I’ll send my email address.

Answer (score 1):

the text is “丁巳年夏月劉墉寫雨景”, roughly means

in summer of 1977 (丁巳年夏月), 劉墉 (the name of the author) drawn rain scene (寫雨景)

the top seal is “劉墉”, the author name

the bottom seal is “夢然”, mr 劉’s pseudonym (號)

have fun :)